# Need the multiline tooltip

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm developing the small project on Angular 4 + PrimeNG. Not satisfied with a component of the ToolTip, need a multiline tooltip. Who with such problem faced and how to overcome the situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to their documentation: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip. You can notice there's an ability to add a custom class to the tooltip. See

> tooltipStyleClass | string  | null  | Style class of the tooltip.

I believe you can use it to add your own class and then apply any styles you want. Probably remove fixed `height`, setup proper `white-space`, tweak the `position` etc. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Bind your `pTooltip` to a variable in your component which you'll assign it's value using [*Template string*](https://www.techiediaries.com/typescript-template-strings/). That's it!

---

**component.html:**

```
[pTooltip]="multiLineTooltip"
```

---

**component.ts:**

```
multiLineTooltip = `line 1
  line 2
  line 3
  ...
`;
```

---

**Outcome:**

[image]

> Checkout this simple [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-multi-line-tooltip-so47110595) to see this in action

Answer (score 3):

By default tooltip value is taken as text.
Set `escape` property to false which will enable the escape characters

```html
<input type="text" pTooltip="Line 1 <br/>Line 2 <br/>Line 3"  [escape]="false">
```

Comment: 100% this worked for me after trying zillions of options <br> <br/> <br /> &lt; &gt; \n \n\n %0A &#010; %0D %8Bbr%9B %E2%80 %3Cbr%3E and many combos thereof (within primeng tooltip fwiw)